# Invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle

I have this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
 storeName varchar(50),
 keyName varchar(50),
 docname varchar(512),
 config clob,
 CONSTRAINT foo_pk PRIMARY KEY(storeName, keyName)
)
```

And this select statement:

```
SELECT config ,docname
FROM foo 
WHERE storeName = 'SolutionFramework' 
AND keyName = 'Solutions'
```

And this is the error I get:
(42000/904) ORA-00904: "KEYNAME": invalid identifier

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is working on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d151e/1). What version of Oracle?

Comment: Are you sure you created the column as `keyName` and not as `"keyName"`? The latter preserves case in the name and forces you to refer to it in a case-sensitive manner, i.e. as `"keyName"`.

Comment: and here is a sqlfiddle demo for @KlasLindbäck suggestion http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cb76/1

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes around keyName in CREATE TABLE command.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers are nothing but a name that is given to oracle object. The object could be constant, variable, exception, cursors, procedures, function, package, trigger, object type, reserve word or label. Make sure you have used the same column name.